# Would a device with different power rails become one if both rails are shorted to ground

Tags: repair

I'm trying to repair a nintendo switch that seems to have multiply shorts to ground.
The shorts to ground are on the 3v3 rail and on the 1v8 rail.

I seem to be getting continuity between the two different rails so if i was to inject power into one rail would the other rail become powered aswell.

What I'm asking is would the separate rails become joined if both are shorted?

Comment: If both are shorted to Gnd then by "logic" they are tied together or common to gnd. But are they really shorted to gnd or is there some milliohm difference?

Comment: If you are using the "continuity test" on a DVM to indicate a short, be aware that that test on most meters merely indicates a low apparent resistance (~40 Ohms for one of my meters), and not an actual Zero Ohm short.  The apparent resistance will likely vary depending on the meter polarity.

Comment: I do get different resistance to ground from the two lines, so if they were both full shorts to ground would the reading be the same?

Comment: If they were full shorts to ground, you'd read 0 ohms (or very close) from either to ground **and** from rail to rail.

Comment: I just feel that the 86 ohms to ground that i get on a 3v3 rail seems very low

Comment: 86 ohms to ground on a 3.3V rail is just under 40 mA of current consumption. It is likely that the circuit on 3.3V consumes much more than that under normal operation. What is this "Nintendo switch" that you are trying to repair, and what is the actual problem with it?

Comment: The nintendo switch is a handheld gaming device, I was thinking that there was a short circuit to ground but the machine does boot up but the battery seems to drain quickly even when the device is not in use  (sleep mode).